# How can I align this tables in the same row?

Tags: tables, arrows

I have the following code:

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
  \centering
\tabcolsep=0.5cm
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{13pt} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
\cellcolor{white}1 &\cellcolor{white} 1 & \cellcolor{black}\color{white}0 \\
\hline
\cellcolor{black}\color{white}0& \cellcolor{blue!10}$P_0$ &\cellcolor{white}1 \\  
\hline
\cellcolor{black}\color{white}0&\cellcolor{black}\color{white} 0 &\cellcolor{white} 1 \\  
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{subfigure}[h]{0.2\textwidth}
$\mbox{\Huge$\rightarrow{}$}$
\resizebox{8cm}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
\cellcolor{white}1 &\cellcolor{white} 1&\cellcolor{black}\color{white}0&\cellcolor{black}\color{white}0&\cellcolor{white}1&\cellcolor{black}\color{white}0&\cellcolor{black}\color{white} 0 &\cellcolor{black}\color{white} 0&\cellcolor{white} 1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
$\mbox{\Huge$\rightarrow{} 201$}_{10}$
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Calcularea numarului regulii de tranzitie}
\end{figure*}\par
```

The output looks like this:[image]

I want to put on the same row the matrix after that it should be an arrow after it I want to put the array and then an arrow tot he number 201. All of this I want to be in a sigle row aligned. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: `\begin{figure*}[h]` `figure*` is for figures that span both columns of  a two-column document and does not have an `[h]` option. If you have a single column document `figure*` is the same as `figure` but it is better to use `figure`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the following is closer to the expected output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[h]
  \centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{13pt} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
\cellcolor{white}1 &\cellcolor{white} 1 & \cellcolor{black}\color{white}0 \\
\hline
\cellcolor{black}\color{white}0& \cellcolor{blue!10}$P_0$ &\cellcolor{white}1 \\  
\hline
\cellcolor{black}\color{white}0&\cellcolor{black}\color{white} 0 &\cellcolor{white} 1 \\  
\hline
\end{tabular}
$\rightarrow{}$
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
\cellcolor{white}1 &\cellcolor{white} 1&\cellcolor{black}\color{white}0&\cellcolor{black}\color{white}0&\cellcolor{white}1&\cellcolor{black}\color{white}0&\cellcolor{black}\color{white} 0 &\cellcolor{black}\color{white} 0&\cellcolor{white} 1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
$\rightarrow{} 201_{10}$

\caption{Calcularea numarului regulii de tranzitie}
\end{figure*}\par

\end{document}
```